# Can org-publish-project-alist follow symlinks?

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I use `org-publish-project-alist` to maintain my personal webpage. On my local machine, I have dozens of git-repos where I develop files I want to share on my webpage. Currently, I'm using hardlinks to include these files in my project. Recently, I've realized that this project would be easier to maintain if I could put symlinks to my files in my project directory and have org publish the actual files that the symlinks point to. Is this possible?

For instance, suppose I have a file `foo.pdf` in a directory `mylocaldir` on my machine

```
$ tree /home/me/mylocaldir/
/home/me/mylocaldir/
├── foo.pdf
```

I'd like my org project to have a symlink pointing to `foo.pdf`

```
$ ln -s /home/me/mylocaldir/foo.pdf /home/me/myorgproject/foo.pdf
```

When I publish `myorgproject`, I'd like emacs to publish the file `foo.pdf` as a `pdf`, not as a symlink.